Slip ring induction motor rpm control
My friend and I are reviving an old extruder for making filament and the screw speed is too fast to start the cooling line.
It is powered by a very unique motor which I've never heard before.
Elektra-Farndau DNR 3/14 s50d

We found video of the motor operation (the motor version in the video has additional motor for changing the commutator brushes position):
https://youtu.be/0hVaM0QyL9Y?si=6l_G8_0fNn2Vz9Hq
Working principle of the motor according to the maker of the video:
The rotor has standard 3 phase coils for 3 phase 400 V connected via slip rings to 3x 400 V power.
The rotor also has dc coils which is connected to the commutator and powers the stator winding through it. You can change the position of the comuttator brushes, which changes the voltage on the stator -> changes the motor speed.
My question is:
If it is possible to lower the rpm of the motor even more by using a vfd?
